# Transforming hoverable navigation bar on desktop to a clickable navigation bar on touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

The following question is regarding a website I am building.

One of the main categories on my navigation bar displays a group of sub-categories (internal page links) when the mouse is hovered over it.  To achieve this I simply use the *:hover* command in my CSS code.  The problem is that when my site is viewed on a touch screen device,  I am able to toggle open the sub-categories by clicking on the :hover element (which is what I want), but I am not able to toggle off the sub-categories by clicking on the *:hover* element.  Once they are clicked open on the touch screen device (Iphone 6s Plus), they are stuck open unless I refresh the page.

**MY QUESTION:** Is there a way that I can maintain the *:hover* function on non-touch-screen devices while simultaneously allowing touch screen users to toggle off the element by clicking it?

I know how to write Javascript (using *onclick*) to toggle the display of elements on/off through click, but if I do this then I lose my :hover capability.  I'm wondering if there is a line of code that will do the following: **execute the onclick function if and only if the device is a touch screen device.**

Comment: You could run the media query inside the onclick function to check if you are on a touch or mobile device or not, and depending on your needs you can consume the event to stop propagation (ignoring the user clicks). More info here: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the following code to distinguish devices. Add you hover css with touch-disable.   

detectTouchEvent: function(){
jQuery.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;
var $body = $("body");

if(jQuery.support.touch){
$body.addClass("touch-enable");
}else{
$body.addClass("touch-disabled")
}
}
```